# Ubuntu 13.04. Just did software update... Not logging in

Tags: 13.04, updates, login

I just did a software update through Software Updater and re-booted the machine.  Now I can't log in as myself...  I can only log in as a guest.

When I try to log in as myself, I get a terminal-like screen stating starting Apache server, and it loops right back to the login screen....  Tried it 10 times.

What happened and how can it be fixed ??

---

Update...

Even when logged in as a guest, my user name shows on the System Menu ( the 0/1 icon) at the top right, beside the time display).  Switching users there sends me through the same login loop.

Comment: Can you log in as yourself from terminal after pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Answer (score 0):

I used <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to login at the virtual terminal.

Then I ran:

```
sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Please ask a new question for the "can other than .Xauthority be deleted".